# Updating keys and values persisted using NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying out an app where I persist an array using `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(<array>, forKey:<keyName>)`

I am trying to achieve the following but want some help as I am a total newbie. I think these are common requirements (have seen them in a few apps) but am unable to find ways in swift.

1. The array grows dynamically and I want to be able to store the updated array or add the new values later using the same key. I think that if I overwrite the same key with the new array there will be quite a bit of overhead as the array grows bigger. Is there a better way to do this ? To overcome this I am currently batching the values and storing multiple arrays.
2. I want to be able to change the name of the key at some other point, like a key rename. I believe there is a way to increment some sort of 'refcount' on the object, delete the old key and add a new key. I could not find ways in swift to do this but have seem some ObjectiveC methods. I am currently using a sort of name-redirection layer and working around this.

Comment: NSUserDefaults is great for small amounts of data such as user preferences, but it sounds like your requirements go well beyond that. Have you considered alternatives, such as Core Data?

Comment: @Clafou thanks for the pointer and no, I haven't yet tried CoreData. Will that achieve the above ? I am learning as I go using a tutorial and there has been no discussion of CoreData yet.

Comment: Look into it, there are tons of tutorials. It would certainly be better with the two concerns you listed, as it would seem over the top to write custom code to do such things using NSUserDefaults. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSUserDefaults isn’t a good place to store a lot of data so it may not be the right thing to use in your case. Not sure how much data you are storing but keep that in mind. You’ll find more info just by googling for “ios persist data”

There is no way to ‘update’ the data. For example, on an array you’d have to write the whole array back out.

To update a specific item in your array you have to read the whole array, modify it and then write the whole array back to disk.

Any code you could post would be helpful in case I did not properly understand your question.

Comment: thanks for the pointers from you and @Clafou, I will figure out other ways to achieve the same rather than using NSUserDefaults.

Comment: If you are in a pinch continue using NSUserDefaults with the above caveats, but wrap it into a custom class (i.e. DataManager class). Have have the app call methods in DataManager that manage the data and when you are ready to move to something else you only need to update the methods in DataManager. When you change this could be CoreData, sqlite, Realm, Parse, custom code, etc. Just normal OO best practices. Good luck...